# How microservices are managed using Mantl?

Tags: docker, microservices

Recently I came across [Mantl](http://microservices-infrastructure.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/index.html) ( microservices infrastructure management project by Cisco). Its an opensource one and they have  pushed it on [github](https://github.com/CiscoCloud/microservices-infrastructure#deploying-on-multiple-servers). I didn't understood their basic working. Does anyone have any idea about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, Mantl is a collection of tools/applications that ties together to create a cohesive docker-based application platform. Mantl is ideally deployed on virtualized/cloud environments (AWS, OpenStack, GCE), but I have just recently able to deploy it on bare-metal.

The main component in Mantl is Mesos, which manages dockers, handles scheduling and task isolation. Marathon is a mesos framework that manages long running tasks, such as web services, this is where most application reside. The combination of mesos-marathon handles application high-availability, resiliency and load-balancing. Tying everything together is consul, which handles service discovery. I use consul to do lookups for each application to communication to each other. Mantl also includes the ELK stack for logging, but I haven't had any success in monitoring any of my applications, yet. There is also Chronos, where scheduled tasks are handles ala cron. Traefik acts as a reverse-proxy, where application/service endpoints are mapped to URLs for external services to communicate.

Basically, your microservices should be self-contained in docker images, initiate communications via consul lookup and logs into standard io. Then you deploy your app, using the Marathon API, and monitor it in Marathon UI. When deploying your dockerized-app, marathon will register you docker image names in consul, along with its' exposed port. Scheduled tasks should be deployed in Chronos, where you will be able to monitor running tasks and pending scheduled tasks.

Comment: Thanks Pejal. Currently I am focusing only on Mesos( 0.27.0) + Marathon(0.15.1).  I'm able to run simple tasks through marathon on mesos slave like file creation etc. But, I'm not able to start containers on mesos slave from  marathon UI. Tasks are getting failed. Do you have any idea ?    
Set up is like this-      
3 mesos-masters having zookeeper for leader election.  
1 mesos-slave having docker installed and one ubuntu:14.04 image.